# Spyder does not update to V4

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Updating spyder does nothing. My system is still stuck on V3. Can someone help me get this onto V4 please?

I start the Anaconda navigator.

I start Spyder V3.3.6

A prompt informs me that Spyder 4.0.1 is available.

I follow the instructions at : https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html

Open an Anaconda command window and type: conda update spyder

Get the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda update spyder
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \

Updating spyder is constricted by

anaconda -> requires spyder==3.3.6=py37_0

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: I did google it. There were a few answers but they did not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run `conda update anaconda` to update your anaconda version then update your spyder version using `conda update spyder`

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Grantx ! I tried this, but Terminal returns `zsh: command not found: conda`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try in the "Anaconda prompt", not your regular terminal

Answer (score 4):

I am listing all my steps, as I'm not sure exactly what steps permitted what other steps.

I also had Anaconda installed for managing and using Spyder 3.3.6.  When I ran Spyder, I get the message `Spyder 4.1.5 is available!`.  I ran Anaconda Navigator as Administrator, and in the Home tab, the Spyder Settings menu showed `Update Application` grayed out.  This persisted even if I entered the Environments Tab and clicked on `Update Index...`.

I opened an Anaconda Prompt as Administrator and ran:

```
conda update --all
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

I also got the following message:

```
Updating spyder is constricted by

anaconda -> requires spyder==3.3.6=py37_0

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I closed the Anaconda Prompt and opened a new one, in case that was needed for the updated Anaconda to work.  I re-issued `condate update spyder` but got the same message as above.  I confirmed that Spyder is still at version 3.3.6.

I re-ran Anaconda Navigator.  This time, Spyder's `Update Application` was not grayed out, but clicking on it only caused a brief spinning circle.  The Spyder version was not updated.  I re-entered the Environments tab and re-clicked on `Update Index...` and waited for it to finish.  In Anaconda Navigator's Home tab, in Spyder's Settings menu, I was then able to `Install specific version > 4.1.5`.